# C++ write_function writes "Nan" instead of proper value

Tags: c++

I have an assignment to make a class with a figures and i have to use constructors to implement it. The problem is my write function only writes properly the value of the given circuit but neither pole nor circuit. Instead of writes "nan".

I have added "debbuging couts" to check if the function counts the pole and circuit properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class Figura
{
protected:
    double pole;
    double circuit;
public:
    virtual double funkcja_pole(double A) = 0;
    virtual double funkcja_circuit(double B) = 0;
    virtual void write() = 0;

    Figura(double, double);
};

class Circle: public Figura
{
private:
    double radius;
public:
    Circle(double);

void write()
{
    std::cout << "Radius = " << radius << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Pole = " << pole << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Circuit = " << circuit << std::endl;
}
double funkcja_pole(double A)
{
    pole = 3.14 * A*A;
    std::cout << "pole:" << pole << std::endl;
}
double funkcja_circuit(double B)
{
    circuit = 3.14 * 2*B;
    std::cout << "circuit:" << circuit << std::endl;
}
};

Figura::Figura(double POLE, double CIRCUIT):
    pole(POLE), circuit(CIRCUIT) {}

Circle::Circle(double RADIUS):
    radius(RADIUS), Figura(funkcja_pole(RADIUS),funkcja_circuit(RADIUS)) {}

int main()
{
    Circle my_circle(2);
    Figura *wsk;
    wsk = &my_circle;
    wsk->write();
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual and expected output. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It doesn't matter how you organize your member initialization list, it always initializes base type first, then members in the order they appear in your class definition. It looks like you intend `radius` to be initialized first, but it won't be.

Comment: Please listen to your compiler warnings which should have told you that your functions do not return any values. If you got no warnings enable them by using `-Wall` compiler flag.

Comment: You are right @Yastanub - i have just turned it on. Anyway - i use GNU GCC compiler but do you recommend any other, better ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning the computed values:

```
double funkcja_pole(double A)
{
    double pole = 3.14 * A*A;
    std::cout << "pole:" << pole << std::endl;
    return pole;
}
```

You should refactor your code so that everything is a little bit more organized:

```
class Circle: public Figura
{
private:
    double radius;
public:
    Circle(double);

void write()
{
    std::cout << "Radius = " << radius << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Pole = " << pole << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Circuit = " << circuit << std::endl;
}
private:
double funkcja_pole(double A)
{
    double pole = 3.14 * A*A;
    std::cout << "pole:" << pole << std::endl;
    return pole;
}
double funkcja_circuit(double B)
{
    double circuit = 3.14 * 2*B;
    std::cout << "circuit:" << circuit << std::endl;
    return circuit;
}
};

Figura::Figura(double POLE, double CIRCUIT):
    pole(POLE), circuit(CIRCUIT) {}

Circle::Circle(double RADIUS):
    Figura(funkcja_pole(RADIUS),funkcja_circuit(RADIUS)), radius(RADIUS) {}
```

Comment: You could as well get rid of the local variables in `funkcja_circuit` and `funkcja_pole` since it seems like they were supposed to initialize the members. Or it was wanted that they change the members in that case they should still do.

Comment: @Yastanub Oh yes, I agree. I just kept the local variables because of the display for OP.

Comment: I see you have only added "private:" segment into the code - did you mean about any other improvments to make my code look more organized?

Comment: Also the initialization order iirc